# Which one is first: determinant and cofactor matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The determinant of a square matrix $A_{n\times n}$ is defined by

$$\det A = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} \ C_{ij}$$

which, by the definition of the cofactor matrix, is

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} \ (-1)^{i+j} M_{ij}$$

But here the minor matrix is the determinant as well. So the definition becomes recursive. Which one comes first?

Comment: The expansion by minors (or cofactors) is **not** the **definition** of the determinant.

Comment: That's typically how textbooks introduce determinants to high school students. They should be rather honest and explicitly mention "today we are going to learn about determinants, how they look like, how to evaluate them and what their properties are, unfortunately it is rather complicated at this stage to define _what precisely is a determinant_". Everyone has to go through such misery in their math education.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Very good observation, one can only fully empathise with it!

Comment: @curious There is nothing logically incorrect about a recursive definition of determinants. The key is to note that the determinant $1 \times 1$ matrix is simply the number in that matrix.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh What is the precise definition?

Comment: You have to understand a little bit about permutations before you can get to the real definition of determinant. Another approach is to treat it as linear alternating functions of rows of corresponding matrix such that it takes value $1$ for identity matrix. These approaches are best presented in standard linear algebra texts meant for undergrads.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: yes I admit the recursive definition works but the proof that determinant has same value whichever row or column is chosen is real tough. I kept on wondering and wondering for two years of my high school and never figured out this. Later Hoffman and Kunze present the alternating linear function approach in their text _Linear Algebra_ and almost every thing about determinants looks easy, natural and a lot more demystified.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I actually have that book. And about linear algebra in general (not about Hoffman) I was really fascinated by the idea that "a vector is an element of a vector space". Before understanding that I was only able to think about vector as an arrow in 3D space. Before I couldn't get why the concept of a vector and inner product are defined weirdly in Hilbert space and used in quantum mechanics but now everything became much clearer. So my question is, as a first year engineering student who's just starting to learn about linear algebra, shall I try to read Hoffman in depth?

Comment: I don't think you need to read all of Hoffman text. It does cover some advanced stuff. I myself read the chapters on determinants and matrices (simultaneous linear equations, rank etc) just in time high school ended. So finally the high school mystery of determinants was taken care of in high school itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First comes the determinant a $1\times 1$ matrix (its one and only entry), then comes cofactor matrix of a $2\times 2$ matrix, then comes determinant of a $2\times2$ matrix, then comes cofactor matrix of a $3\times 3$ matrix, then comes determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix and so on.

*Added:* Some further remarks and precisations:

- your second formula seems incorrect or out of context. The logically correct statement at that point of your sentence should be $C_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}\det \widehat{A^{ij}}$, where $\widehat{A^{ij}}$ is the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix such that $$\widehat{A^{ij}}_{kh}=\begin{cases}A_{kh}&\text{if }k<i\land h<j\\ A_{k+1,h}&\text{if }k\ge i\land h<j\\ A_{k,h+1}&\text{if }k<i\land h\ge j\\ A_{k+1,h+1}&\text{if }k\ge i\land h\ge j\\ \end{cases}$$
- by the previous remark, you can see that this definition of determinant is recursive, in the sense that the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix is defined via the entries of the cofactor matrix, which are determinants of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices.
- we could debate about which one is the base case. For instance, I assumed it to be the $1\times 1$ determinant. I could be slightly more precise and say that it is the $1\times 1$ cofactor matrix, which is by all means always the matrix $1$. I could also have said that it was the determinant of the $0\times0$ matrix, which authors generally either define as $1$ or don't define.

Answer (score 5):

Your determinant formula becomes problematic only if it allows for infinite loops. However, you won't fall into an infinite loop, because for any $n\times n$ matrix, you can (eventually) reduce the calculation to the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix, which is
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=ad-bc.$$
And, even the determinant formula for $2\times 2$ matrices can be deduced from the cofactor formula, in which case we simply use the fact that the determinant of a $1\times1$ matrix $(j)$ is $\det(j):=j$.